# The Stack Exchange bot is doing my dice rolls instead of the Dice Service bot

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Apparently [the Stack Exchange chat bot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-2) has developed a special place in its heart for me.

Most people attempting a dice roll get a reply from [the Dice Service bot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-93/dice-service). But not me! The Stack Exchange bot follows me around with its own personal set of dice. When ***I*** request a dice roll, the Stack Exchange bot shoves the Dice Roller out of the way excitedly and does the rolling itself. This can be seen in [our dice roller playground transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/16836) (where we discovered it was *me specifically*), in [general chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24460742#24460742), and in [other rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24460929#24460929).

While I'm flattered and feel privileged that it's following me around personally, and while it might get tired after a day or two and leave me alone again, I should probably report this as a bug and encourage it to return to other business.

Comment: Are you using any scripts or other extensions that might be messing with the chat? I suspect we're both using your Fudge dice script, so that on its own can't be the cause.

Comment: I have SOUP and the Fudge dice script. This occurs even with Greasemonkey disabled. I have Privacy Badger, Self-Destructing Cookies, and Adblock Plus, but I've had all of those addons for weeks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That can happen when for whatever reason (usually a network hickup or something like that) we fail to load the dice user. In that case we just use the default system user for a while. Whether or not this happens to a particular user depends on whether or not they are hitting the particular web server where this happened (which is a 1 in 9 chance), that's why it happened to you but not others.

I have restarted chat, so you should see the dedicated dice user again.

Comment: [I'm getting the dice bot again.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24462505#24462505) Thanks, now we know what's going on if this happens to someone else in the future.